# Laravel won't load class

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to use the following library, [this](https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth).
It all seems pretty use but doesn't seem to work for me. I've added the stuff the the composer.json and I also updated the app.php. Then I ran `composer dump-autoload` in the laravel directory.

I still seem to be getting the same error..

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: Adding the stuff to `composer.json` and `app.php` isn't all you need to do. Did you run `composer install` after making the `composer.json` changes?

Comment: @ceejayoz I did, sorry for not mentioning. Edit: I ran it again and this time it did seem to execute, last time it just threw a few lines. I think it works now, thanks.

Comment: `$php artisan optimize`

Comment: Have you tried clear all cache ?  `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 4):

Try to install this package by this command:

```
composer require invisnik/laravel-steam-auth
```

You will install the latest version of current package and update your **composer.json**, **composer.lock** and **autoload** files.

Comment: I do tend to prefer the `composer require` approach. Not sure why more READMEs don't recommend it.